# Can I get Ubuntu with ros preinstalled anywhere?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a new computer for my robot that I cannot connect to the internet where I work. I have another work computer that I do connect to the internet at work. I can download the Ubuntu installation to a thumb drive using the connected computer and install it on the robot computer, but when it comes to installing ROS I have to take the robot computer elsewhere to do so. The connected computer is very locked down and I can't install things like offline-get or anything that accesses the internet. It is a pain in the butt, and I'll probably end up removing the computer from the robot and taking it else where, I just figured I'd ask first.

Does anyone know if anyone provides Ubuntu installations with ROS preinstalled (I want to use Indigo on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04). I see there is a VM provided by nootrix that has this, but I don't want to use a VM, is it straight forward to strip the image from the VM and install it on the real computer? Also I don't know much about Docker, is my problem something the ROS Docker stuff might help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220100/can-i-get-ubuntu-with-ros-preinstalled-anywhere?/) by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3460 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2015-10-29**:
You might be interested with this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2015-10-30**:
Thanks, I've tried Keryx, it's similar to offline-get in that I need to install software on my connected computer that needs internet access which isn't possible with the firewall. The answer about making a usb copy of the Ubuntu repo is interesting though. I might give that a try at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's `.iso` image that bundles Ubuntu and ROS https://github.com/tork-a/live-cd

If you take a look at the generator script, [ros-%DISTRO%-desktop-full is already installed](https://github.com/tork-a/live-cd/blob/821ea8831b075a77d214c25cd41c8a3c13fad979/00-create-cd.sh#L81), as well as specific packages starting from [this line](https://github.com/tork-a/live-cd/blob/821ea8831b075a77d214c25cd41c8a3c13fad979/00-create-cd.sh#L132).

Also, if you are already running Ubuntu and only want to install ROS without internet connection, you can create a thumbdrive using the .iso image from there and use it as the local DEB repository.

See [readme](https://github.com/tork-a/live-cd/blob/master/README.md) for the usage. And pull request is welcomed.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2015-10-30**:
I'll look into this and report back. Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2015-11-20**:
This worked like a charm, I actually didn't even have to mess with the script, there was already an image in the archive that had everything I need. I tried to find the archive link to paste it here for others but couldn't find it again.